# function and const that works like instanceof

Tags: typescript

How to build a function and a const that do the same as instanceof?

First some declarations:

```
let anyValue: any;
let arrayValue: Array<string> = [];

class Animal<T,U = boolean> {
    constructor(prop1: T, prop2: U){
        this.prop1 = prop1;
        this.prop2 = prop2;
    }
    prop1: T
    prop2: U
}
```

instanceof keeps the type of the value:

```
if(arrayValue instanceof Array ){
    arrayValue
//  ^? let arrayValue: string[]
}
```

But on any the value is converted to the given class and sets all generics to any:

```
if(anyValue instanceof Array ){
    anyValue
//  ^? let anyValue: any[]
}

if(anyValue instanceof Animal ){
    anyValue
//  ^? let anyValue: Animal<any, any>
}
```

My function should do the same, but any is now unknown

```
function instanceOf<C extends new (...args: any[]) => any>(obj: any, cls: C): obj is C extends new (...args: any[]) => infer V ? V :never {
    return obj instanceof cls;
}

if(instanceOf(arrayValue, Array)){
    arrayValue
//  ^? let arrayValue: string[]
}

if(instanceOf(anyValue, Array)){
    anyValue
//  ^? let anyValue: unknown[]
}

if(instanceOf(anyValue, Animal)){
    anyValue
//  ^? let anyValue: Animal<unknown, unknown>
}
```

Using instanceof the unionValue is converted after the if-block

```
function foo(unionValue: string | Array<string>){

    if(unionValue instanceof Array){
        unionValue = unionValue[0];
    }
    unionValue
//  ^? (parameter) unionValue: string
}
```

Using a constant which saves the result of instanceof the unionValue is not converted after if block.

```
function bar(unionValue: string | Array<string>){

    const isArray = unionValue instanceof Array;

    if(isArray){
        unionValue = unionValue[0];
    }
    unionValue
//  ^? (parameter) unionValue: string | string[]
}
```

A function which gets the instanceof result as an parameter
How can the parameter know that it is a guard?

```
function doit(isArray: boolean, unionValue: string | Array<string> ){
    if(isArray){
        unionValue = unionValue [0];
    }

    unionValue
//  ^? (parameter) unionValue: string | string[]
}

let unionValue: string | Array<string> = ["Hello", "World"];
let isArray = unionValue instanceof Array;
doit(isArray, unionValue);
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAGwpgLgBAhgdgTwGoxAVzALlog3KSWAJyJmVQ2wEESyAeAZwiIEs4BzAPigF4oBtALr5gAYxAwGDKFTgsAtqjoAVADQBVXlABGAe13h43AN7Ao5qKN1wmRNKIi6iACgAORXa4CM2NVHeeAEzY6gCUphaRUBAAFiwMAHQB3lrJXvhRFrHxSR6ugal5gRkWAL5mFmm%20FebJwVDqwOXAAPQtbEzwomC6AGZQANZgYK7SsWDRCK4TfdExEwBuFGDALL3OMLTk6BMdEF09-TSkCFDhNcQnKDutLeYAegD8TcC3OmjQ8KebE1ZwC2AiBAwAATaK6OYTdgsAFwSwSKQ4MEMSDSVAgKDsMBwQEsURjCFfV5rDaIa4YKB7A6zY5kM4RCxfckrNoPZ7NElM5aUmz7ODdGlyRQY86RLk3VlQJ4vW7yU69ND8iAsaxQBgxXRoEBgkEQ8ZqmDyMCqd6fRCU6RwXQAdygioGVutcGACqVKrhVP5YAA8r06ABhKBgAAewLgIMtYFtzgSsc27AY2C%20QlCvG4X04zl02gAVknECbxImoP7QthszmLSWg6HsRGoDjo7GEvHi8nBKmeNw2L1AVAkFBHv2oJgcQCiFAGeYiJA0EQ4RWeZ0vbMi-gOetPd1fRstsyTbSEKFRYy98s3lL2cTN7yDjvxRgD1tj1OcNsMBfpRvnFufesH8aMhCqgL4XABn5Xq8bRoAwbDsEufICv0irusyVZ-OOwJgjAvTAhO%20prAAtNoIC6KIAyvK6DjulAvT6M4KHWMy2C2HBUAAD4yFsjDMHBnDnBcJKMXAaG-jSz6vpEwloXw0nLPwAAMwgXOUUlyEx56Sl%20UEtDBbEwJY1jLtA1pxKIMQGgCYzzFAM4MFq0CzGJ-T6nJOxQDEkiQgaRqTNMsDSNoYB0TOCSUYq1GqtomwMepInLCxvEcBxXEnDxrAcPxpgXH8TAWoeWhuRSzmpWQIiRCS8SHiemRFRMslxcyinKZEqkWHVEEyqyBlUcqqqmXiFlYhA1m7LeK79HZDkBTg-ibIakCAm8%20quPNRp4VAupgJaujQA6NomrEMDQCwJ1opiaCbCCLoRX1cK6qdP4MIe2B6AYYDwCadWJRl8GcYe6V8fSgmbs9EkXGpqHcg1UPuc1JTmM0kMaRKdyXjK4DQN9apJX9pUIIDmVaPwABEAASYAgKRJMmiTADqTjaiTymY-lWyFY13IlYe%20APRAT2Hl9nM7KEIhAA)

Comment: This is two distinct questions; the answer, if any, for a function that behaves like `instanceof` will have very little to do with the answer, if any, for a const that behaves like `instanceof`.  Please [edit] the post to ask just one of these questions, and open a new post for the other one if you want.